# Using OData with a non-wcf | non-oData end point?

Tags: .net, json, rest, service, odata

Is it possible to use OData on the client side to easily communicate with a non-wcf and or non-oData endpoint (service)

The service I wish to consume is JSon based and is Restful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better off using a .NET REST client like one of the following:

- [WCF HTTP](http://wcf.codeplex.com/)
- [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/)
- [Hammock](http://hammock.codeplex.com/)

They all easily support JSON and REST features.